# How to check if an UI Element has reached the top of the page in windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

There is a page which has a scroll viewer and some content which is dynamic in nature. In the middle of the page there is a grid. Whenever the user scrolls the page and grid reaches the top of the page i want a notifier. Basically i want to make the grid sticky on top whenever it reaches top of the page. Is there any way we can achieve this in Windows phone application. I dont want to calculate the offset because the content between top of the page and grid is dynamic.

Comment: Only way I came close for this without a bunch of verticaloffset work and watching property changes and crap was a bit hacky, but it worked fine. I just put a transparent rectangle in behind the top content of width=1 with an x:Name so it sized with the dynamic content above. That will supply your offset boundary to identify when your object has reached the top of the scrollviewer viewport. So basically IF scrollviewer verticaloffset >= ElementName=Rectangle ActualHeight THEN you've reached the top of the object. Wish I still had the source so I could look exactly but that's the gist.

Answer (score 3):

This used to be tricky to do but thanks to the new [Windows Composition API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.composition.aspx), it's now fairly simple.

Let's say I have a `ScrollViewer` named `MainScroll` which hosts a `Grid` called `StickyGrid` and I want to make the latter *sticky* once it hits the top.

There's the code with comments to explain what it does.

```
MainScroll.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
{        
    // Let's first get the offset Y for the main ScrollViewer relatively to the sticky Grid.
    var transform = ((UIElement)MainScroll.Content).TransformToVisual(StickyGrid);
    var offsetY = (float)transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0)).Y;

    // Get Composition variables.
    var scrollProperties = ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet(MainScroll);
    var stickyGridVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(StickyGrid);
    var compositor = scrollProperties.Compositor;

    // Basically, what the expression 
    // "ScrollingProperties.Translation.Y > OffsetY ? 0 : OffsetY - ScrollingProperties.Translation.Y"
    // means is that -
    // When ScrollingProperties.Translation.Y > OffsetY, it means the scroller has yet to scroll to the sticky Grid, so
    // at this time we don't want to do anything, hence the return of 0;
    // when the expression becomes false, we need to offset the the sticky Grid on Y Axis by adding a negative value
    // of ScrollingProperties.Translation.Y. This means the result will forever be just OffsetY after hitting the top.
    var scrollingAnimation = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("ScrollingProperties.Translation.Y > OffsetY ? 0 : OffsetY - ScrollingProperties.Translation.Y");
    scrollingAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("ScrollingProperties", scrollProperties);
    scrollingAnimation.SetScalarParameter("OffsetY", offsetY);

    // Kick off the expression animation.
    stickyGridVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", scrollingAnimation);
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/StickyHeader_WindowsComposition) is a working demo on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the solution. But I need something which works on windows phone 8.1 also. This works just for UWP apps.

Comment: I am currently using ViewChanged Event ` int x; ` . But the problem is ViewChanged gets called after the scroller is scrolled. So i can clearly see the header getting scrolled out of the view and then coming back and sticking to the top.

Comment: `  private void OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e){  if (!e.IsIntermediate){  var verticalOffsetValue = scrollviewer.VerticalOffset;var maxVerticalOffsetValue = scrollviewer.ExtentHeight - scrollviewer.ViewportHeight;var item = (Grid).TransformToVisual(scrollviewer).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));if (item.Y <= 0){ if (item.Y < 0) {scrollviewer.ViewChanged -= MyscrollbarScrollViewer_OnViewChanged;scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalOffsetValue + item.Y);}}

Comment: Thanks for your great work @Justin XL!!

Weird thing, I applied this same thing to a ListView so that it's Header would "stick", but it didn't work. Does this apply to a ListView too?

Comment: @JustinXL, found my problem :) I had an ItemContainerStyle which set a background color, so the items under the sticky grid would "scroll over" it, essentially hiding it because of the back color. Is there an easy way to perform a "bring to front" for the Sticky Grid? Such as a z-order change?

Comment: @MassimoCacchiotti I just updated my GitHub demo. Basically, all you need to do is set `Canvas.SetZIndex(StickyGrid, 1);` to bring the sticky element to the front. :)

Comment: Great!! Thanks so much Justin, I like your work you do on composition, you're very good :)

Comment: @MassimoCacchiotti thanks! :) The new Composition API is indeed super exciting.